# Fetch data from database and show in custom module's form

Tags: forms, database

I used the following code in my module to build a form :

```
$form['promo_type'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => 'Promotion Type',
  '#options' => array(t('Digital Coupon')),
);
```

I want the `option` data as dynamic, fetch from database. How can I do that?

Comment: Also, how to dynamically populate an array is quite a plain PHP question; the only part that is Drupal-specific is which function to use to get data from a database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [db_select](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) to fetch data from database. Create an array of values :

```
$result = db_select('table', 't_alias')->fields('t_alias', array('id', 'title'))->execute()->fetchAll();
$options = array();
foreach ($result as $value) {
  $options[$value->id] = $value->title;
}

$form['promo_type'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => 'Promotion Type',
  '#id' => 'promo_type',
  '#options' => $options,
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```